# Удалить повторяющиеся значение из списка вместе с ним

Tags: python, list

Всем добрый день

Надо чтобы в input вводился какой-то список, и выводились только уникальные values из него(тоесть не повторяющиеся)

Имеется следующий код:

```py
import ast

dict1 = input("")
d = ast.literal_eval(dict1)

temp =[]
res = dict()
for key, val in d.items():
    if val not in temp:
        temp.append(val)
        res[key] = val


print(*list(res.values()))
```

К примеру ввод может быть вот таким: `{"2":1,"5":1,"55":1,"34":2,"0":3}`

Тогда output должен быть вот таким:`2 3`

Но пока ответ получается только `1 3 2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посчитать количество повторений каждого из значений в словаре. Для этого отлично подойдёт класс [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Затем оставить только те значения, у которых получившийся счётчик равен единице.

```
from collections import Counter

d = {"2":1,"5":1,"55":1,"34":2,"0":3}

res = [k for k,v in Counter(d.values()).items() if v == 1]
print(*res)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё работает.Тоже когда-то думал надо таким кодом